# Checkboxes and jQuery (determine which ones are checked, get their name tag value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to programming and I have a problem which probably is easy to solve, but I haven't been able to do so so far... So,  I have a number checkboxes and by using jQuery I would like to determine which ones are checked and then get the value of their name tag ideally or their id. How can I do that? Thanks! :)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="something1">
<input type="checkbox" name="something2">
```

etc.

Comment: Neither of these checkboxes have a value though - they have a name-attribute (you can add a `value="something"` attribute). And both can be checked at the same time.

Comment: `var names = $(':checkbox:checked').map( e => $(e).attr('name')).get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all selected checkboxes by using the following selector:

`$("input[type='checkbox']:checked")`

Then you can then loop over this using jQuery's `.each()` method and get each of the selected checkbox's `name` attribute by using `.attr("name")`.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("name"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="something1" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="something2" />
<br />
<button class="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for :) I will try it out and hopefully it will work for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.On click of checkbox the name of the checkbox is printed.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('input').change(function(){console.log($(this).attr('name'))})
          })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="something1">
<input type="checkbox" name="something2">
```